# powershell script to remove all content items for french version in sitecore

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I wanna use this script to remove all content items for french version and leave the English version in sitecore but wanna make sure it looks good before excuting it :(

```powershell
cd 'master:/sitecore/content'

function FilterItemsToProcess($item) 
{
    Get-Item $item.ProviderPath -Language "fr-CA"
}

$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$itemsToProcess = Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | foreach {FilterItemsToProcess($_)}
if($itemsToProcess -ne $null)
{

    $itemsToProcess | ForEach-Object { 
        | remove-item
    }
}
```

Comment: Wanted to make a note about your provided script. PowerShell knows that `@()` is an array so no need to specify the type. Also, the ForEach-Object command is not needed if the command (like Remove-Item) can accept the pipeline data as an input. For example, Get-Item piped to Remove-Item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Miroo,

One thing you need to know is that `Remove-Item` always removed the item as a whole. It does not remove just the language even if you pipe a language specific version. This is because sitecore API always returns an item in a specific language and `Remove-Item` has no way of disregarding the intent.

What you need to use for the purpose is the `Remove-ItemLanguage` commandlet.

e.g. in the following example I'm creating a "Test" item in my content then adding a Polish version to each of those items and in the next step deleting the polish versions.

```powershell
New-Item master:\content\ -ItemType "Sample/sample item" -Name test -Language en | Out-Null

foreach ($i in 1..10) {
    New-Item master:\content\test\ -ItemType "Sample/sample item" -Name $i -Language en | Out-Null
}

Get-ChildItem master:\content\test\ | Add-ItemLanguage -TargetLanguage pl-pl -IfExist Skip | Out-Null

Get-ChildItem master:\content\test\ | Remove-ItemLanguage -Language pl-pl
```

Your script could be as simple as following:

```powershell
$path = "master:\content"
@(Get-Item $path) + (Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse) | Remove-ItemLanguage -Language "fr-CA"
```

Comment: Adam, thank you for pointing out my mistake in using Remove-Item rather than Remove-ItemLanguage. I'll make note of that for the future.

Comment: Thanks allot :) That helped allot

Answer (score 1):

I would begin with the following:

```powershell
$path = "master:\content"
@(Get-Item -Path $path -Language "fr") + @(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Language "fr" -Recurse)
```

Once you know for sure that this is the list of items you want to remove, you can pipe those results to `Remove-ItemLanguage`.

```powershell
$path = "master:\content"
@(Get-Item -Path $path -Language "fr") + @(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Language "fr" -Recurse) | Remove-ItemLanguage -Language "fr"
```

Check out our Gitbook for more details [here](http://michaellwest.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/). The section about working with items covers getting by version and language.